# A problem with thmtools

Tags: errors, theorems, thmtools

I updated my TeXLive yesterday and `thmtools` is being problematic...

Running `pdflatex` on the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

is resulting in

```
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/opt/TeX/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.277     \ifthmt@isnumbered\else *
                                   \fi
?
```

The particular file where this happens, `tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty`, has not changed (and I had no problem with the package a couple of days ago!), so something else is causing the error. I have no idea how to chase it, though.

Ideas?

Comment: I can be of no more help than to say that I can reproduce the problem with updated TeX Live in Ubuntu.

Comment: I run MacTeX2011, and I can confirm that I can't compile your MWE either since running the latest package update, during which the entire `oberdiek` suite of packages was updated. Running `tlmgr restore` to revert to the previous version of the `oberdiek` suite restores the ability to compile your MWE. This strongly suggests that one or more of the packages of the `oberdiek` suite are causing the problem you're encountering. Judging from the `.log` file, the list of "suspect" packages comprises `kvsetkeys`, `infwarerr`, and `etexcmds`.

Comment: I'll take a look this evening. I've had advance warning that a new release of `kvsetkeys` would break thmtools (yet again), apparently that has been released now. Until then, the workaround is to revert to the previous version of `kvsetkeys`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be fixed in v63 available [here](http://absatzen.de/thmtools.html). Unless something major crops up, this version will go to CTAN early next week. (Testrunning it is much appreciated.)